# How to tell Google that there is no amp version

Tags: amp-html

I've converted some sites of a website to have valid amp html. Based on if the specific page supports amp, I conditionally render the required `amphtml` link or don't.

My problem is that when I look into the Google Search Console, I can see that many sites which aren't converted and therefore don't have a `amphtml` link in their header, are being scanned for amp html errors - and of course have errors as they're not valid. Additionally the Chrome browser's amp plugin doesn't recognize an amp version of these pages.

Is there a way to prevent not-amp-supported pages from being validated or doesn't it do any damage if they are validated? I'm wondering because I have about 18 valid sites but no amp search results for my website when I search Google. I thought that maybe these errors prevent my site from showing up in the search results at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to notify Google that your amp page is stand alone and a non-AMP page does not exist include this line in the header of your file.

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.yoursite.com/your-amp-page.htm">`

`your-amp-page.htm` is a circular reference, i.e. this line is placed inside `your-amp-page.htm` and so the page references itself.

This tutorial might help you out.  It goes over the basics of how to set up an AMP page for search engines with diagrams.
[How I Used AMP For My Small Business Website](https://www.cleanpaw.com/amp_small_business.htm)